# Hiding non-working time in MS Project

Tags: project-management, microsoft-project

How can one hide the non working time in MS Project? I mean I want the calendar zone of the gant chart not to display weekends and holidays. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot hide the display of Saturday and Sunday in the Gantt chart view. You can
show a "5 day" week in the Calendar view.

Answer (score 1):

Although Mark is right you can try a work around by setting the non-working days color to the same color of the working days. By default this means to set it to white.

Answer (score 1):

It it not possible to omit the weekends; however, you may right-click on the Gantt Chart and choose **Non-working Time... > Formatting options > Draw: In front of task bars**.

This essentially covers up the weekend portions of the task bars.

This only makes a difference when you are zoomed in on the Gantt Chart; when you zoom out it doesn't make a difference. I keep hoping that Microsoft will add a feature to omit the weekends from the Gantt Chart view, or that someone will create an add-in to do this. This would be the greatest add-in.